# Cron (and systemd) in centos7 in docker

Tags: docker, cron, centos7, systemd

I want to run cron in a centos7 OS running in docker. When I try and start crond I get:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Googling shows that that is because systemd is not running. But when I try and start that I get:

```
bash-4.2# /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system --unit=basic.target
systemd 219 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
Detected architecture x86-64.
Set hostname to <7232ef24bdc8>.
Initializing machine ID from random generator.
Failed to install release agent, ignoring: No such file or directory
Failed to create root cgroup hierarchy: Read-only file system
Failed to allocate manager object: Read-only file system
```

Anyone know how I can run crond here?

Comment: Run `/usr/sbin/cron -f` in the container and not through systemd

Comment: That gives me `No such file or directory`. I do have the `cronie` package installed.

Comment: which centos image are you using?

Comment: FROM centos:centos7

Comment: You need to install `crontabs` and run `crond -n` if your would run it as the main CMD, or `crond` if you would run it as background process

Comment: Use timer outside your container that calls docker exec.

Comment: Right, "crond -n" is what the docker-systemctl-replacement script did also detect from the standard *.service scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick check whether that could work with the [docker-systemctl-replacement script](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement). What that script does is to read *.service files (without the help of a systemd daemon) so that it knows how to start and stop a service.

After "yum install -y cronie" I was able to "systemctl.py start crond" in which case I can see a running process "/usr/sbin/crond -n". It is possible to install the systemctl.py as the default CMD so that it will also work on simply starting and stopping the container from a saved image.

Answer (score 0):

You can run cron service inside docker in this manner:

Map etc/cron.d/crontab file inside the container, the crontab file should contains your cronjobs, see cronjob examples below:

```
@reboot your-commands-here >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
@reboot sleep 02 && your-commands-here >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
0 * * * * your-commands-here >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

In your Dockerfile:

```
chmod -R 0664 /etc/cron.d/*
# Create the log file to be able to run tail and initiate my crontab file
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log && crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

# Run the command on container startup
CMD /etc/init.d/cron restart && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD /etc/init.d/cron restart && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

#start supervisor 
ENTRYPOINT ["service", "supervisor", "start"]
```

To run cron under supervisor use this config:

```
[program:cron]
command=    cron -f
startsecs    = 3
stopwaitsecs = 3
autostart    = true
autorestart = true
```

Comment: Should I run cron or crond?

Comment: in your case if you are running centos, use crond

Comment: When I try and start it with the supervisor it does not stay up. But if I start it by hand it does stay up. What could be wrong with the supervisor startup?

Comment: supervisor needs to start in no daemon mode. you want the below in you supervisord.conf                    [supervisord]                                                    nodaemon=true

Comment: I am running it in no daemon mode.

Comment: Hey Larry, i edited the answer above, please see the the CMD to start the cron and the supervisor ENTTRYPOINT

Comment: This did not work for me. I finally got to to work by just running crond from my entry point script run.sh Thanks for your help just the same.

Comment: i recently found this from docker captain that validates the process. maybe it can help: https://jonathas.com/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-on-docker